# Python Module Consisting Only of a Single String

Tags: python

It seems to be legal Python code to have a file consisting only of a single quote-enclosed string. The Python interpreter will not complain about the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"somevalue"
```

If I wanted to keep some one-off value (say an API key) isolated from other configuration settings, is it possible to import a file like this into another script as a module and use the string?

The default string representation of the imported module will be something like `<module x from y-path>`. Can the string value contained within that module be somehow accessed?

(To preemptively cut off tangents, I understand I could just read the file as text or assign the value to `variable` and `from module import variable` in another script. There are more conventional ways to accomplish related goals. I am asking out of a desire to better understand the language's design and capabilities.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That string actually ends up being the docstring for the module.
So it is accessed by the `__doc__` attribute of the module.
Python picks up the first loose string it finds in a module, class, or function to determine its docstring.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring

Answer (score 1):

You can also retrieve your string by using `inspect`. Which is almost the same as `__doc__` except that it also got "cleaned up" by [`inspect.cleandoc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc)

```
import inspect
value = inspect.getdoc(__import__('filename'))
```